# Set Vertex Normal X Y Z values Individually

Tags: normals

Can we edit the vertex Normals similar to Maya, where you can set the X, Y, Z values individually between 0-1, or is that not possible in blender yet? In my specific case, I need my X and Z values to be 0, and the Y value to be 1.

Comment: How do you intend to use these normals? In shading? For export?

Comment: Its suppose to be a grass asset for Unreal Engine, fbx export.

Comment: Hey not sure if you found a solution yet but here's a tutorial. https://youtu.be/FT-QfuzoQEk?t=153 I came from the same grass tutorial :)

Comment: Is it split normal vectors or vertex normal vectors?